# Comparing Coefficients in Summations

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, convolution

Suppose I have the following equality:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-a}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{j}\frac{f(a,k)\cdot g(b,n-k)}{n!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-a}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{a}\frac{z^k \cdot g(b,n-k-a)}{n!}$$
for multivariate functions $f,g,$ and with $a,b,z\in \mathbb{C}$.   Considering we are talking about finite sums, I feel like I can just simply drop the outer summation, drop the first binomial number $\binom{n}{k}$ and then drop the $n!$ as well since they are common for all terms in each summand.  Thus I could say that, more simply,

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}f(a,k),g(b,n-k)=\binom{n-k}{a}z^kg(b,n-k-a)$$

I don't see the problem in this.  I think because the $n$ dropped out I'll need to address the fact that $n>k$ in my final solution, but is this simplification okay?

Comment: excuse my ignorance but  where is the dependence on z on the left hand side  - somehow hidden in the f(a,k)?

Comment: Yes, my apologies.  I should have said that f and g are polynomials in $z$.

Comment: In that case I would be cautious about removing the summation signs because different powers of z are or might be distributed across each of the n-a terms. Unless you could show linear independence of the terms in the summand you cannot really justify removing the summation. Although I must admit the finer details of this topic are not known to me.

Comment: That's why I put in on the website here. It didn't seem right to me but because f and g were polynomials, I had a thought that it could be worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Why would it be okay? If $1+2+3+4+25 = 5+6+7+8+9$, does that mean that $1=5$ and $2=6$ and ...?

Calling the two sides of your second equation $L_k$ and $R_k$, you are given that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-a} \binom nm L_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-a} \binom nm R_k$, and you're trying to deduce that $L_k = R_k$. This is just false. The $R_k$ might be the $L_k$ in reverse order, or every $R_k$ might be $0$ except $R_0$ equals exactly what it needs to equal for the first equation to hold, etc.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a typo in the question. If it's supposed to be two polynomials in a variable z it might be reasonable. Title says co-efficients but the z in LHS doesn't appear explicitly.

Comment: I thought I wrote that they wwere polynomials in $z$. Yes, they are polynomials in a variable $z$.

Comment: I don't think that changes anything.